# What is this Mortal Kombat II manual?

Tags: mortal-kombat-2

Cleaning my computer-related old boxes I cam across a torn (missing pages) MKII manual and I was wondering what it is. I tried searching for it online but didn't find it or any reference to it. It contains a review of the moves of every character as well as strategy to beating the bosses, and there are a few extras there too.

I scanned 2 pages, one is the back cover (I think, pages are missing after all) and one randomly selected for demonstration.

[image]
[image]

I can scan more if there is request for it.

What is this manual, who published, is it available online? Any additional information is welcomed.

Comment: If i was to guess I would say it is the arcade version of MKII. It makes a reference to Holding back and press HP...There is no such button labelled HP in SNES, Sega, etc...

Comment: @ryekayo Couldn't it be the PC version?

Comment: I'm not sure. Never played the PC version. This guide looks vaguely familiar...I remember seeing it when I was a kid but just not exactly sure for what system....

Comment: I found this PDF of the [SNES version manual](http://gamesdbase.com/Media/SYSTEM/Nintendo_SNES/manual/Formated/Mortal_Kombat_II_-_1994_-_Acclaim_Entertainment.pdf) (I remember the ad for Maximum Carnage on my SNES copy as a kid!) and it doesn't match what you found.  It is interesting that it doesn't list the individual buttons for HP and HK on each character, just a table up top saying which button does which action (probably easier to do when making the manual for different systems).  Still, quite different from your manual here.

Comment: @PawnInGameOfLife I found the one you posted already in my initial search. Thanks for the input, though,